# Does Meta Tag "Viewport" Property Behave in Emails the Same As the Standard Web Page?

Tags: html, email, gmail, html-email, meta

Context: I am trying to maintain some old code (an email template specifically) and I need to make it mobile **readable** (not necessarily good-looking). The old code I am talking about was basically created specifically for the desktop view as a priority. Due to time constraints, I thought about utilizing the meta "viewport" property.

My knowledge: I am very well aware that emails behave very differently from the ordinary web page and most of the layouts are usually done using table elements due to minimal support of various CSS properties.

My markup:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=670">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <!-- email content -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Notice the code `<meta name="viewport" content="width=670">`. This is what I am trying to make work in the email. My testing environment currently is the Gmail app on Android & using Chrome while using dev tools mobile view.

What I noticed is, despite adding this meta tag, the content does not adjust to treat any device to "become" width=670 like it would normally function if done on a normal web page (i.e., not on email).

Am I doing something wrong or missing something? Or perhaps it is being overridden by the email client? Does meta tag "Viewport" property behave in emails the same as the standard web page?

N.B., I realize that this might come off as an XY problem for some of the viewers. It is not. I really want to know, for knowledge's sake, on how to make this work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure exactly how viewport works in emails, but you can also try giving you outermost table a width of 670 to force it to be 670 on mobile and desktop

Answer (score 2):

Typically, mobile clients will try and do their own scaling, and as such I believe the `<meta name=viewport...>` is overridden or ignored.

If the email is simple, i.e. one column, a `<div>` approach might suffice, but otherwise as you say, everything is done in tables for the sake of Outlook desktop rendering.

Readability in mobiles typically comes down to whether the content in the email is an appropriate size for viewing. If you have images that are set to widths greater than about 300px wide, and they do not have mobile overrides, *the mobile client will scale the entire email down, to potentially unreadable size*.

For something simple, you could add this:

```
@media screen and (max-width:620px) {
 img {
    width:100%!important;
    height:auto!important;
}
```

There can be other such content that gets in the way, like other fixed width block elements, or long unbreakable words (much less often), that will also force resizing.